# startActivity in onStop does not work

Tags: android, android-activity

```
@Override
public void onStop() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, StatusActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent.setAction(AppConstants.ACTION_DISPLAY).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));


    super.onStop();
}
```

This does not work why?
the StatusActivity does not receive the intent in onCreate or onNewIntent
if I put the code anywhere else then it works but not in onStop or onPause

It seems that the intent is sent correctly but StatusActivity is not receiving it right away. It does receive it only if I send another intent from another place and then receive them both at the same time.
For testing I sent 10 intents in on start and then after few secconds I sent another intent from a service and the  StatusActivity received 11 intents all at once.

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:excludeFromRecents="false"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
     android:taskAffinity=".MainActivity"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
    android:name=".StatusActivity"
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
    android:excludeFromRecents="true"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:launchMode="singleInstance"
     android:taskAffinity=".StatusActivity" >
```

Comment: First of all you can not sure about every time onStop() will be called becz some device memory problem onStop() will not be called but onPaush() will be definitively called.

Comment: what you want to acheive??

Comment: I want that after activity A is closed (after onStop) the activity B is showed. I don't care if it not works all the time

Comment: How do you make your activity A `onStop`?

Comment: with onBackPressed and sometimes with finish.

Comment: The activity B needs to be started only after activity A is no longer visible (onStop)

Comment: I'd suggest putting a log message inside onStop() and see if it logs anything when you expect onStop() to be called.

Comment: I already have logs everywhere. I had to remove them in post because are too many

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, StatusActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have test your code and find out that when I press back button, activity B will be called, but when I press home button, it doesn't.

I guess the reason is that when home pressed, system call launcher apk by component or action(I'm not sure), but back pressed didn't. And your activity B is hidden by launcher.

I don't think call activity B in onStop method is a suitable way, becz you can't control the invoke time. But I find a another way to acheive that:

```
protected void onStop() {
    finish();
    super.onStop();
}

public void finish() {
    startActivity(your intent);
    super.finish();
}
```

It is just a workaround, not a good solution.

Hope it helps.

Comment: my problem is that when I press back button activity B is NOT called and wish it is. I don't want activity B to be called when press home (that is also against google policy)

Comment: @Chris,try start activity in `onBackPressed`or `onUserLeaveHint` , can it works？

Comment: in onBackPressed it works, in onStop it does not. the problem is that I need to start the activity after the current activity is stopped. I eventually sent a broadcast to the service where it works also and from there I used startActivity. It is so surprising that it does not work in onStop. I was thinking maybe it is because of the taskAffinity